# Specify Python version in Microsoft Azure WebJob?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, azure, azure-webjobs

How can I select which Python version to use for a WebJob on Microsoft Azure?

When I do `print(sys.version)` I get `2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]`

Where can I specify another version? I would like to use Python 3 for some jobs.
I have tried adding `runtime.txt` reading `python-3.4` to the root path, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also if you wanna run different python versions in the same site, you can always drop a `run.cmd` that calls the right version of python for you. They are installed in `D:\Python34` and `D:\Python27`

Comment: This answer is more useful than changing the python version in the Azure Portal, because changing it there changes the `web.config` file and disables .net functionality in the web services. (I use a .net web service in combination with python web jobs)

Comment: How do you make the WebJob run the run.cmd script instead of the standard run.py?

Answer (score 1):

Azure WebJobs run in the context of your App Service plan.

By default, the python version is 2.7 (as you've discovered). To change this, you'll need to look at the settings for your App Service plan and change the python version.

Here's an example, from one of my App Service plans. Initially, it was unset, but I changed it to 3.4:

[image: python version settings]

I also created a test webjob in python:

```py
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

I ran it before changing the python settings:

[image: python 2.7 output]

I then changed the python version to 3.4 in the App Service settings, and ran it again:

[image: python 3.4 output]

Comment: Actually, this disables (or overrules?) the .net functionality which we use for our Web App, so ahmelsayed's answer is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Beside David Makogon’s answer, we also can configure the python version in current [Azure manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

In the manage portal of your Azure Web Apps, in configure tab, under general section, we can specify the python version which will be configured in your Web App runtime. Restart your site after your saving your configuration.
[image]